# Unable to createand append divs and spans dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a HTML code that has a div say `y` and this is in my HTML body and there is a button. when user clicks on this button, I want to do the below.

1. Create another div (with class as `smallBar`)
2. Inside this `div`, I want to create 3 spans.
3. Add this(total `smallBar`) content to div `y`.

Here is my current code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="y" id="y">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv()" value="click me" />
```

**JS**

```
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "smallBar";
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.className = "span1";
  var span2 = document.createElement("span");
  span2.setAttribute("class", "span1");
  var span3 = document.createElement("span");
  span3.setAttribute("class", "span1");

  div.appendChild(span1);
  div.appendChild(span2);
  div.appendChild(span3);

  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div;
}
```

here when I click on the button, Instead of creating a `div` it is giving me message as `[object HTMLDivElement]`. please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d9hg0vkk/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

You are assigning div element directly. Where as you should get it's innerHTML

https://jsfiddle.net/d9hg0vkk/2/

Once you click the button and inspect element and see. You see span's inside of your target div.

```js
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "smallBar";
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.className = "span1";
  span1.textContent= "span1"
  var span2 = document.createElement("span");
  span2.setAttribute("class", "span1");
  span2.textContent= "span2"
  var span3 = document.createElement("span");
  span3.setAttribute("class", "span1");
  span3.textContent= "span3"

  div.appendChild(span1);
  div.appendChild(span2);
  div.appendChild(span3);

  document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="y" id="y">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv()" value="click me" />
```

Or if you want to append whole div, you can try using appendChild as others pointed

```
document.getElementById("y").appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using `innerHTML` instead you need to use `appendChild()`

```js
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "smallBar";
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.className = "span1";
  span1.innerHTML="Spam1";
  var span2 = document.createElement("span");
  span2.setAttribute("class", "span2");
  span2.innerHTML="Span2";
  var span3 = document.createElement("span");
  span3.setAttribute("class", "span3");
  span3.innerHTML="Span3";

  div.appendChild(span1);
  div.appendChild(span2);
  div.appendChild(span3);

  document.getElementById("y").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div class="y" id="y">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv()" value="click me" />
```

**P.S**- InnerHTML gives/sets a String, representing the HTML content of an element. When you do `document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div`, it takes it as a String and not as a Object and thus you see `[object HTMLDivElement]` in the div. Instead you can do it with `innerHTML` like this `document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div.outerHTML;`

[Read More about innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use innerHTML and not appendChild which appends the div every time you click on the button, you have to use

```
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div.outerHTML;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div;
```

Because 'div' is HTMLDivElement Object and innerHTML accepts only string. By using outerHTML you retain the 'smallBar' Div as well. if you use

```
 document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

you'll see only 3 spans inside div 'y' and not 'smallBar' Div.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to [Sanchit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47977867/402037)s `.appendChild()` is [`.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```js
function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "smallBar";
  div.textContent = "div";
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.className = "span1";
  span1.textContent = "span1";
  var span2 = document.createElement("span");
  span2.setAttribute("class", "span1");
  span2.textContent = "span2";
  var span3 = document.createElement("span");
  span3.setAttribute("class", "span1");
  span3.textContent = "span3";

  div.appendChild(span1);
  div.appendChild(span2);
  div.appendChild(span3);

  document.getElementById("y").insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", div);
}
```

```html
<div class="y" id="y">

</div>
<input type="button" onclick="createDiv()" value="click me" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying like this?

```
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = "<div>ABC</div>";
```

**Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/d9hg0vkk/1/