# Can't display a table [object HTMLTableElement]

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to do a table that displays dice-playing results. When I try to print the table to the HTML-page using innerHTML, I get [object HTMLTableElement].

```
  let rounds = prompt("How many rounds?");
        let Table=document.createElement("table");
        let row=document.createElement("tr");
        const header1=document.createElement("th");
        header1.textContent="Dice 1";
        const header2=document.createElement("th");
        header2.textContent="Dice 2";
        row.appendChild(header1);
        row.appendChild(header2);
        let cell = document.createElement("td");
        let result = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
        

        for (let i=0; i<rounds.lenght; i++) {
            row.appendChild(cell);
            row.appendChild(cell);
            cell.textContent=result;
        }
        document.getElementById("resultshere").innerHTML = Table;
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` is for injecting new content *as HTML source code*; that is, as text. You've built DOM elements, so you want `.appendChild()` to update your DOM.

Comment: Is there a dupe for this? I haven't found something useful... :/

Comment: @Andreas honestly I can't recall seeing this exact situation, at least not recently.

Comment: There it is^^ Only with the wrong accepted answer... @cluelessgirl223: Use the answer with the most upvotes on the dupe target. I've added my `.insertAdjacentElement()` version to the [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74245128/402037)